# Using a C++ class object in fortran 77

Tags: c++, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

Is there a way to pass a C++ object to use with Fortran 77? For example:

```
C23456
      program main
      write (*,*) 'Hello from FORTRAN 77!'
      call readstep('cube.stp'//CHAR(0),myshape)
      stop
      end
```

and then use the myshape as a C++ object which will just be kept in memory used by Fortran and to just pass it to other C++ functions that will actually use it?

EDIT: Here is the C++ code:

```
extern"C" {
    void readstep_(char*,void*);
}

void readstep_(char* inputFile, void* outShape){

    STEPControl_Reader reader;
    reader = STEPControl_Reader();

    int succeed = reader.ReadFile(inputFile);

    if(!succeed){
        std::cout << "There was an error with the input file" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    reader.NbRootsForTransfer();
    reader.TransferRoots();

    TopoDS_Shape myShape = reader.OneShape();
    TopoDS_Shape* myShapePtr = new TopoDS_Shape();
    (*myShapePtr) = myShape;

    outShape = myShapePtr;

    return;
}
```

Comment: Please add at least part of the C++ code.

Comment: Otherwise it would be easier in Fortran 2003 (on my wrist clock it is 21st century!) but you can use integer*4 or integer*8 as an opaque pointer also in old Fortran.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please read tag description of the tag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran-iso-c-binding for much better options. And the many questions and answers there.

I will use the star notation as a common extension.

C++:

```
class Obj{

};

extern "C" {
  void hello_();


  void readstep_(char* name, Obj** ptr){
    *ptr = new Obj(); //use name in the actual process
  }
  void pass_it_(Obj** ptr){
    hello_();
    delete *ptr; //some usage of the object
  }

}
```

It uses pointer to pointer because of the pass by reference.

fortran:

```
  program main

    integer*8 myshape

    call readstep('cube.stp'//CHAR(0),myshape)

    call pass_it(myshape)

  end

  subroutine hello
    write (*,*) 'Hello from FORTRAN 77!'
  end subroutine
```

Use `integer*4` on a 32-bit platform.
(note there is no reason for the STOP statement)

compile:

```
g++ f77c++.f f77c++.C -lgfortran
```

or

```
gfortran f77c++.f f77c++.C -lstdc++

> ./a.out 
 Hello from FORTRAN 77!
```

Comment: Vladimir F thank you for your answer! My code is not working quite yet. But it was definitely an improvement. Here is how I assign the object `TopoDS_Shape myShape = reader.OneShape();
    *shape = new TopoDS_Shape();
    *shape = &myShape;` However I am not sure how to access the data when I pass back the object to C++

Comment: That is wrong, you are passing a pointer to the local variable `myShape` which is on the stack. Do it like in my example without the local variable. `*shape = new TopoDS_Shape();` `**shape = reader.OneShape();`  (But even better is to make a propper RAII constructor.)

Comment: What you have suggested is working. Thank you very much for your help and I am sorry for any silly mistakes(I am not familiar with double pointers :P)

Comment: Just for the record. Was my previous approach wrong because the local variable myShape would be destroyed after the function call and the pointer would point to a deleted value?

Comment: Exactly, the value would not exist after the return.