# Fortran code calling openCASCADE does not work, pointer hell?

Tags: c++, pointers, fortran, fortran77, opencascade

I am sorry for the vague title. This question is a continuation of a previous question posted 
here: [Using a C++ class object in fortran 77](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761552/using-a-c-class-object-in-fortran-77/) what I need to do is to reuse the objects created from C++ in Fortran.

The code that I am dealing with is a very simple Fortran code:

```
C23456
      program main
C Pointers to C++ classes. Never use them!
C Just pass them to the C++ functions.
      integer*4 shapeToMesh
      integer*4 faceMap
      integer*4 edgeMap
      integer*4 vertexMap
C We have to append //CHAR(0) to the string since it must be
C Null terminated
      call readstep('cube.stp'//CHAR(0),isuccess,shapeToMesh)
      call createfacemap(shapeToMesh,faceMap)
      end
```

Where the `shapeToMesh` is a class object that contains the geometry that is parsed from the
input step file. The `faceMap` `edgeMap` `vertexMap` are objects that assign a unique integer to each face edge and vertex respectively

Now the `readstep` or `readstep_` (note that those are C++) function works good and here is the code:

```
//SuccessInt contains information about successful loading
//of file. 1 for success, 0 for failure
void readstep_(char* inputFile,int* successInt, TopoDS_Shape** shape){

      //Print out the filename received from fortan for debug reasons
    int len = strlen(inputFile);
    std::cout << "Input file ";
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        std::cout << inputFile[i];
    std::cout << std::endl<< std::endl;

    //This has a private contructor. So I must first declare
    //and then call the constructor.
    STEPControl_Reader reader;
    reader = STEPControl_Reader();

    int succeed = reader.ReadFile(inputFile);

    if(!succeed){
        std::cout << "There was an error with the input file" << std::endl;
        (*successInt) = succeed;
        return;
    }
    reader.NbRootsForTransfer();
    reader.TransferRoots();

    //Assign memory, then opject
    *shape = new TopoDS_Shape();
    **shape = reader.OneShape();

    (*successInt) = succeed;
    return;
}
```

As you may have already seen from my Fortran snippet, the next thing I want to do is to create a list of my faces present in the shape. To do this I call the `createfacemap` or `createfacemap_` function the code of which is shown below:

```
void createfacemap_(TopoDS_Shape** shape, TopTools_IndexedMapOfShape** map){

    TopoDS_Shape ashape = TopoDS_Shape();
    ashape = (**shape);

    if(ashape.IsNull())
        std::cout << "Shape is null";

    *map  = new TopTools_IndexedMapOfShape();
    TopExp::MapShapes(ashape,TopAbs_FACE,(**map));
    std::cout << "Faces: " << (**map).Extent() << std::endl;
    return;
}
```

But instead of 6 Faces I get a result of 0 faces. To investigate any further, I debugged the
program using a point. And the results can be seen in the screenshots
[image: Debug Screenshot 1]
[image: Debug Screenshot 2]
[image: Debug Screenshot 3]

It can be seen that the map variable is initialized and some processing goes on since the
NbBuckets change, however the size does not change at all that means that there are no objects stored. I am using the openCASCADE library. Here are the relevant references:

http://dev.opencascade.org/doc/refman/html/class_topo_d_s___shape.html
http://dev.opencascade.org/doc/refman/html/class_top_exp.html
http://dev.opencascade.org/doc/refman/html/class_top_tools___indexed_map_of_shape.html

any help would be really appreciated!